# Plotly doesn't draw barchart from pivot

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am trying to draw a bar chart from the CSV data I transform using pivot_table. The bar chart should have the count on the y-axis and companystatus along the x-axis.

I am getting this instead:
[image: Bar chart not showing]

Ultimately, I want to stack the bar by CompanySizeId.

I have been following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oM8NV-y6wmE&list=PLH6mU1kedUy9HTC1n9QYtVHmJRHQ97DBa&index=11&t=0s).

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.offline as pyo
import pandas as pd

countcompany = pd.read_csv(
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/redbeardcr/Plotly/master/Data/countcompany.csv')

df = pd.pivot_table(countcompany, index='CompanyStatusLabel',
                    values='n', aggfunc=sum)
print(df)

data = [go.Bar(
    x=df.index,
    y=df.values,
)]

layout = go.Layout(title='Title')

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

pyo.plot(fig)
```

Code can be found [here](https://github.com/redbeardcr/Plotly)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you flatten the array with the `y` values, i.e. if you replace `y=df.values` with `y=df.values.flatten()`, your code will work as expected.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.offline as pyo
import pandas as pd

countcompany = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/redbeardcr/Plotly/master/Data/countcompany.csv')

df = pd.pivot_table(countcompany, index='CompanyStatusLabel', values='n', aggfunc=sum)

data = [go.Bar(
    x=df.index,
    y=df.values.flatten(),
)]

layout = go.Layout(title='Title')

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

pyo.plot(fig)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that since version 4.0 plotly is offline only. Check [this](https://medium.com/plotly/plotly-py-4-0-is-here-offline-only-express-first-displayable-anywhere-fc444e5659ee)